# ways to pass variables through php/html file? require()/include() or function()?

Tags: php, function, variables, include, require

I have a `output.php` file, which combines HTML and PHP contents.

**index.php** has

```
<?php
     require("output.php");
?>
```

Which way is a better way to pass variables? Should I have

```
<?php
     $variable = $_GET['r']; //this is some variable that will be passed into output.php
     require("output.php");
?>
```

Or would using a function() be better so I can pass some kind of variables

```
<?php
     $variable = $_GET['r'];
     echo output($variable);
?>
```

**output.php**

```
function output(variable){
    //html and php
}
```

But, I'm not so sure if HTML can be used inside a function? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to me its better to use functional approach. The function can be used in several files.As far as Html is concern it can support there is no such problem in that. I will suggest you to user functional approach.

Comment: wouldn't i still have to require the php that has the function to pages to allow function to work?

Comment: ya ...you have to include that file but stil it will provide useability and modularity of the code..